# What determines the methods listed by python's help()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following python file, `test.py`:

```
from math import floor
from logging import getLogger
```

When I do the following:

```
$ python3
>>> import test
>>> help(test)
```

I see this:

```
Help on module test:

NAME
    test

FUNCTIONS
    floor(...)
        floor(x)

        Return the floor of x as an Integral.
        This is the largest integer <= x.

FILE
    ...
```

**Why is the `floor` method documented in the help text, but `getLogger` is not?** More broadly, what determines which methods are listed in a python module's help text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For modules, you can take a look at the [`docmodule`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/903a3e8d67b61594c0fa17fb201769ca924b38f8/Lib/pydoc.py#L1114) method that generates this help text.

In a nutshell, built-in functions (like `floor`) are listed (see the [`isbuiltin`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/903a3e8d67b61594c0fa17fb201769ca924b38f8/Lib/pydoc.py#L1145) call in the condition) while functions not belonging to the module you've called help on don't get listed (that's what the `inspect.getmodule(value) is object` takes care of). I'm not certain *why* this decision was made.

This can be overridden by you if you define an `__all__` variable that contains the names of the functions/variables/classes to be visible.

Apart from these, you also have some special names that don't get picked up (e.g names starting with `_`). You can see how this is taken care of by looking at the [`visiblename`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/903a3e8d67b61594c0fa17fb201769ca924b38f8/Lib/pydoc.py#L186) function that is called for most of the names in your module.